# Math Induction Proof

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-writing, induction

I'm having a little bit of trouble with this proof.

Use mathematical induction to show that $f_{n−1} \cdot f_{n+1} − f_{2
n} = (−1)^n$ for $n$ in the set of positive integers.

I know that in recursive functions, at least the first term is provided and then you could play around with it to come to a conclusion.

I was maybe thinking of using the Fibonacci numbers definition as a guide but I'm not really going forward.

Comment: You can not show that without additional info about $f_n$.

Comment: What are the $f_t$?

Comment: $f_n$ is the FIbonacci sequence. Does the identity involve $f_{2n}$ or $f_n^2$?

Answer (score 0):

**Hint** $\ $  Take the determinant of $$  \left(\begin{array}{ccc} 
1 & 1 \\\
1 & 0 \end{array}\right)^n\ =\ \left(\begin{array}{ccc}
f_{n+1} & f_n \\\
f_n & f_{n-1} \end{array}\right) $$

Comment: If @jake0991 is just starting off with proof by induction it is unlikely that they know enough about determinants to make this useful.

Comment: @QthePlatypus It's actually quite simple. If anyone has questions then ask and I will elaborate.